# How do I update the list of available commits in Netbeans/Mercurial?

Tags: netbeans, version-control, mercurial

I have a NetBeans project linked to a remote Mercurial repo that I'm trying to update to the most recent commit, however, when I open the update window it does not show the most recent commits.  The most recent one available is a tip that's a few months old but the logs on BitBucket say that it's been updated as recently as a few days ago.  I am on the same branch as that commit, so why would it not show up in the list?